# Ember Controller Property, Promise, and Scope

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

Very new to Javascript and even newer to Ember here, I have an async hasMany association and I'm trying to sum a property on the child model (tournament) in the parent models controller.  My understanding of function scope is that the inner functions will have access to everything in the containing functions (except for this), and that's been fine till now. I'm trying to add to amount when the promise resolves, but it must be making a new amount variable because as soon as I make it back to the outter forEach it's back to 0, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  I'm aware I'm not setting the dependencies in the .property(), I just wanted to sort this out first.

```
totalPrice: function(){
    var self = this;
    var allTourn = this.get('model.tournaments');
    var amount = 0;

    allTourn.forEach(function(tournament){
        var tID = Number(tournament.get('id'));

        self.store.find('tournament', tID).then(function(value){
            amount += Number(value.get('buyIn'));
            //amount is set to the buyIn property as expected
        })

        // amount is 0 out here... shouldnt the amount in the promise be using the outter amount variable?
    });

    return amount; // == 0
}.property()
```

**Solution based on Tony's answer**
I moved it to the route and the promise was resolved in the view
routes/package.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('package', params.package_id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model){
    var allTourn = model.get('tournaments');
    var self = this;

    var totalPricePromise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var tournyPromises = allTourn.map( function(tournament){
    var tID = Number(tournament.get('id'));
    return self.store.find('tournament', tID)
      });

      Ember.RSVP.all(tournyPromises).then(function(tournamentList){
    var amount = 0;
    tournamentList.forEach(function(tournament){
      amount += Number(tournament.get('buyIn'));
    })

    resolve(amount);
    controller.set('totalPrice', amount);
      });
    });
    controller.set('package', model);
  }

});
```

Comment: This is how async methods works. The line "return amount;" gets executed even before the promises are resolved (the line with the "then" keyword).

You are correct that the "amount" variable inside the loop is the same variable in the outer scope. But the assignment of value to that variable is done after the "return amount" is executed.

To further understand the order of execution, put some 
"console.log(amount)" inside the "then" method and another one before the "return amount" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like eggward says in the comment, totalPrice is returning amount without waiting for the store.find() promises.  The promises are queued up to run later, sometime after totalPrice is finished.

So, if you have to wait for promises to do the calculation, then you can return a promise from totalPrice, and resolve it when all the store.find() calls complete.  You can use Ember promises' all() method to group the finds.  For example, instead of your allTourn.forEach, you could try something like this:

```
// create a promise to return from totalPrice()
var totalPricePromise =  new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  // create an array of promises from the find() calls.
  var tournyPromises = allTourn.map( function(tournament){
  var tID = Number(tournament.get('id'));
  return self.store.find('tournament', tID)
});

// user RSVP.all to wait for all the finds to complete
// it automatically groups all the results into an array
Ember.RSVP.all(tournyPromises).then(function(tournamentList){
  var amount = 0;
  tournamentList.forEach(tournament){
     amount += Number(tournament.get('buyIn'));
  })

  // this resolve is from the Ember.RSVP.Promise at the top
  // it will finally get to whoever called totalPrice()
  resolve(amount);
});

// return the promise from totalPrice, instead of the amount
return totalPricePromise;
});
```

But the promise may not work well as a property if, e.g. you need it in a handlebars helper.  As an alternative, you could move all the promise stuff to the route where you setup your model, so that in the controller you already have all of the tournaments.  Then you don't have to wait for find() operations in the totalPrice function.

Comment: Cool, when I moved it to the route as you suggested it worked, added the route code.